# Can I incrementally configure the test subject in nexted contexts?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to Ruby and RSpec, and I'm looking for a way to incrementally configure the test subject in nested contexts.  The sort of thing I want to do is illustrated by the following, obviously contrived, example:

```
describe "Array" do
  context "An array" do
    let (:array_length) do
      a = Array.new
      config_array a
      return a.length
    end

    context "with 1 element" do
      def config_array(arr)
        arr << '1'
      end

      it "should have length 1" do
        expect(array_length).to eq(1) 
      end

      context "and an additional element" do
        def config_array(arr)
          arr << '1'
          arr << '2'
        end

        it "should have length 2" do
          expect(array_length).to eq(2)
        end

        context "and yet another additional element" do
          def config_array(arr)
            arr << '1'
            arr << '2'
            arr << '3'
          end

          it "should have length 3" do
            expect(array_length).to eq(3)       
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The tests in this example pass, but I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
# snip      
      context "and an additional element" do
        def config_array(arr)
          parent_context_config_array arr
          arr << '2'
        end

        it "should have length 2" do
          expect(array_length).to eq(2)
        end

        context "and yet another additional element" do
          def config_array(arr)
            parent_context_config_array arr
            arr << '3'
          end
# snip
```

Is there a simple way to do this?  Obviously the real test subject I'm working with is more complex than this.  I'm basically looking for a way to keep the code DRY while adding additional configuration to the test subject in nested contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
describe 'Array' do
  subject { Array.new }

  context '#length' do
    context 'with 1 element' do
      before { subject << '1' }

      it 'should eq 1' do
        expect(subject.length).to eq 1
      end

      context 'and an additional element' do
        before { subject << '2' }

        it 'should eq 2' do
          expect(subject.length).to eq 2 
        end

        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

All the **before** blocks (shortcut for **before(:each)**) in the parent contexts of a given **it** block are going to be evaluated in descending order before the actual **it** code. Together, that forms what we call an example.

The **subject** method is simply syntactic sugar around the **let** method. The first time we call it inside an example the block that we provided in the **subject** declaration is evaluated and its result memoized. Therefore any ulterior call to subject in that particular example would return the same object. 
We take advantage of that in the second example, the one for the two elements. The first **before** calls to **subject** which evaluates **Array.new** returns the array and memoizes it. Then, the **<<** method modifies the now memoized object, that will be modified again in the second **before** block so by the time it reaches the expectation will indeed contain two elements.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think I can work with it, but the code in my question avoids evaluating the *let* method until the *expect* method is run. I have a good reason for that, which I can work around, but it would be nice if I could get those semantics here as well.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code again, what I really want is to abstract the `subject.length` call out of each `expect` clause (my real scenario is a little more complicated).  I could create a method at the top level that returns `subject.length` but is that the cleanest way?

Comment: I would indeed define a method for it scoped inside one of the parent's describe blocks. Inside it you still have all lets and the subject available.

Comment: Thanks again.  This was a big help.